# PHP & MySQL - Changing code ORDER BY

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Hi i have got little problem with my MySQL database.
I have got these things in my database : [image]

When i have code :

```
$show_name = "SELECT name FROM serverlist_comments WHERE location = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$show_name);
$show_carriage = "SELECT carriage FROM serverlist_comments WHERE location = 1 ORDER BY datetime";
$result_carriage = mysqli_query($conn,$show_carriage);
while($row_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
while($row_carriage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_carriage)){
       print($row_name['name']);
       echo " napísal/a toto : ";
       print($row_carriage['carriage']);
       echo "<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

i will receive output :
"Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : ok
Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : niet
Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : ale "

I know it is everything ok cause in date/time 18:17:29 (as "ok") is first and date/time 18:17:32 (as "niet") comes after it

BUT i want to have JUST THE OPPOSITE of this output.
I want output to be:
 
"Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : ale
Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : niet
Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : ok"

Thank you for every answer :D

Comment: You need to read the docs or do a bit more searching before asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add direction to your query:
`SELECT carriage FROM serverlist_comments WHERE location = 1 ORDER BY datetime DESC`

DESC means descending, ASC means ascending.

Answer (score 2):

maybe descending order like:

```
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

or:

```
ORDER BY datetime ASC
```

for ascending order

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you have two loops. If you want to get the output like:

```
Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : ale
Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : niet
Kubajsk0 napísal/a toto : ok
```

you can use following code.

```
$show_carriage = "SELECT name, carriage FROM serverlist_comments WHERE location = 1 ORDER BY datetime DESC";
$result_carriage = mysqli_query($conn,$show_carriage);
while($row_carriage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_carriage)){
       echo $row_carriage['name'];
       echo " napísal/a toto : ";
       echo $row_carriage['carriage'];
       echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Inak som Slovák tak môžeš aj po slovensky

Comment: Ok, ty dva while v sobě nebyly potřeba. Obě informace můžeš vytáhnout jedním dotazem. Ale to už teď asi vidíš sám.

Comment: Jinak DESC je zkratka v dotaze pro řazení descending (sestupně) od nejvyšší hodnoty po nejnižší. Pokud v SQL dotaze nezvolíš řazení, použije se výchozí ASC ascending.

Comment: Ok, ty by si zase mohl označit můj příspěvek jako řešení.

Comment: Dal jsem ti like na příspěvek a posunul všechny komenty. To je asi vše co můžu.